# what is world-writable file?

Tags: linux

I'm facing a problem relating to **world-writable** file. But I don't know what does **world-writable** mean? I tried to google to find answer but I can not find any trustable source which mention about this.

Please help me to explain, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read this:

[https://mason.gmu.edu/~montecin/UNIXpermiss.htm](https://mason.gmu.edu/%7Emontecin/UNIXpermiss.htm)

World-writable basically means o+w (others/write) or 0002.